# Visual studio debugger enter in all the language method/class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with visual studio 2022 debugger. I'm trying to debug my project which use a dll inside the code. So I want to enter in the dll when it is called and continue the debug.
I unchecked the "Just my code" in debug option but the problem is the debug enter in every option/method/property of c# language! For example the method:

```
public virtual object this[int index]
```

or getInteger method and so on.

I want debug just my code and the code of the dll which are called.

I already unchecked the options "Step over Properties and Operators".

Comment: You can configure if "step into" should step into property get/set. But the debugger does not have any setting (at least that I know of) to only step into a particular dll. It only have settings for your code only, or all code. The later naturally includes framework libraries just as much as third party libraries.

Comment: In the debug settings you can try unchecking "Only my code" and then try selecting "Load symbols" in the settings.